# Placement and color of labels in hist() function in R

Tags: r, graphics, histogram

The problem is as follows: I have to place two histograms with `hist(data,labels = TRUE)` function with labels on the same plot. However, the labels may be unreadable as they are colored black in both cases. Can I somehow change their color and placement (e.g. "topright" instead of "top")?

[image: histograms with labels]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You don't indicate what function you are using for the histogram so it is not possible to be very specific. If you are using base graphics, you can always use `text()` to place each label exactly where you want it.